# How to override registration email sent by Firebase from reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am able to code/set up to get registration email from firebase from reactjs application. I would like to override this email and add button like registration link in the email body. I've attached sample email body(received from this website for registration :)). There is a suggestion to use the below function(?!). I am not familiar with this. Can you please help to implement this?. kindly let me know if you need more details about my requirement. Thanks.

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});
```

Sample email:

[image: Sample email]

Comment: What are you referring to by "registration email from Firebase"? Can you share more details on what have you tried so far?

Comment: currently, i am receiving verification email like below. But, i would like make the link similar to a button(sample attached in my initial post). when user click the button(kind), user may be able to verify their email id.

"Hello,

Follow this link to verify your email address.

<Link here >

If you didn’t ask to verify this address, you can ignore this email.

Thanks,

Your project-357608512510 team"

Comment: [Authentication using Email Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) may fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to follow the guidance. Not sure if i need to try that in back end or front end. @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Hi there,
in my front end(react js),
1. i have defined actionCodeSettings
2. then, called createUserWithEmailAndPassword to create user using firebase
3. then, i called getAuth().generateEmailVerificationLink(userCredential.user.email, actionCodeSettings)

when i input email and password from my UI, user is getting created in firebase. But, i am getting below error. Can you please assist?. i am just learning firebase admin functionalities. 

error: "typeError: Object(...)(...).generateEmailVerificationLink is not a function"

Comment: my code
` import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import {auth} from './firebase'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";'
const actionCodeSettings = {
url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
  handleCodeInApp: false,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios',
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12',
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
};
`

Comment: `export const register = async({email, password})=>{
  const useremail = email;
 firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email , password)
      .then((userCredential)=>{
        getAuth()
          .generateEmailVerificationLink(userCredential.user.email, actionCodeSettings)
        .then((link) => {
              alert(useremail+':'+link);
              sendWelcomeEmail(link);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
      })
      .catch(alert);
}`

Comment: `const sendWelcomeEmail=(link)=>{
    alert(link);
}`